# unable to set discount amount programatically

Tags: magento

I am trying to create order programatically. Which is happening perfectly fine. I just don't know how to set discount amount programmatically. which is going to be different for different orders.

Comment: Show us your code. Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom price to a product when you add it into the quote using this:

```
$custom_price = 100; //Products new price for the specific order/customer.
$qty = 1;
$product_id = 210;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

$quoteItem = $quote->addProduct($product, $qty);
$quoteItem->setCustomPrice($custom_price);
$quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($custom_price);
$quoteItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
$quote->save();
```